# Cmake - include_directory... but exclude some?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project structure that looks something like:

```
app
   compile/vs/mingw/etc
   appSrc/cpp/h/etc
   docs/ 
   main.cpp
   build/debug
   build/release
```

As far as I can tell, everywhere where I need this library/etc. I would just do
`include_directories(app)`

but now when I look at External Libraries I can see that apart from `appSrc/` I also got all the `build, compile, docs,etc,etc` Which I do not want to have...

I know this is a bit odd issue... but how can I exclude these "other" directories?
I'm fairly sure my IDE goes bananas as he has 999999 files per library to scan for auto complete/etc... Since I have all the build/etc files in the include_directory path.
Ideally I'd like to

```
include_directories(libPath)
exclude_directories(libPath/xxx)
```

Any hints?

Comment: `include_directories` means "search these directories when using `#include` directives".  As such they should only contain source files, and probably only header files at that.  Therefore it seems `appSrc/cpp/h` is the only directory you need to add.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible. If you cannot use one of the subdirectories, this clearly indicates an issue with the project design. For this exact reason it's a good idea to create a seperate directory containing only the public headers hierarchy; this allows you to do `target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC include)`.

Comment: `but now when I look at External Libraries` - it seems that your question is more about CLion than CMake.

Comment: @r3musn0x Yeah, but the content of these libraries come from me adding include_directories.
I have to refactor a lot of libraries. Was hoping I can "hotfix" the issue with the global CMake flag & exclude the list of folders... ehh fun times. I Will start refactoring... sigh.